# The procedure entry point error when running Qt application executable

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, mingw

I'm trying to run an application developed using Qt using its's executable on Windows.

**Note** that I can run the application directly in Qt Creator without any issu.

Any Ideas?

[image]

Comment: have you copied the executable to another location?

Comment: no I haven't. just I trie to run it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of inspection and using the Dependency Walker software. As you can see in the screenshot the `_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9_M_createERjj` is a function inside libstdc++-6.dll library. I had to add it to my application dependency.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When executing from the IDE, QtCreator runs the executable in a suited environment pointing to the dll used during the build process.

When you try to run your executable manually, you run it in your system environment, which in windows may be polluted by programs installed in your machine with different versions of Qt dlls. This may cause such errors.

You should make a complete deployment of your application [using `windeployqt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193584/deploy-all-qt-dependencies-when-building/41199492#41199492).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've run the windeployqt command. It bring the application dependency but apparently not all dependencies as explained in http://www.brycevalero.com/windeployqtcreating-a-qt-deployable-folder-window   I still have the same issue. I need to know witch dependency is responsable of that issue

Comment: Did you try dependency walker? Looking the error message you posted, the problem may not be Qt but MinGW. You can try to copy the dlls from the `bin` directory of your MinGW installation