# Deploy Qt5 application with cmake on windows

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

For all my other libraries I can use the cmake install command with ${SOMELIB_LIBRARY} but when I use it with Qt5::Core or any other it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deploy all Qt dependencies when building](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193584/deploy-all-qt-dependencies-when-building)

Comment: `Qt5::Core` is *IMPORTED* target, it [cannot be installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175354/can-i-install-shared-imported-library/41179630#41179630).